# Is there any cases when DCL singleton is a better choice than singleton on Holder?

Tags: java, singleton

I've done a little investigation on this topic but I still can't see when Double Checked Locking singleton may be a better choice than singleton on Holder.
It would be great if someone could give me an example.

DCL

```
public class Singleton {
public static volatile Singleton INSTANCE = null;

private Singleton(){

}

public static Singleton getInstance(){
    if (INSTANCE == null){
        synchronized (Singleton.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null){
                INSTANCE = new Singleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
}
```

HOLDER

```
public class Singleton {
    private Singleton() {

    }

    private static class Holder {
        public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: And why do you think that it could be better?

Comment: Instead of the Holder idiom use enum, it's less code with the same effect.

Comment: Well, why don't we use Holder idiom every time then? 
I fail to see why some people choose DCL singleton instead of HOLDER.

Comment: With the Holder scheme you have no real control of when the singleton is initialized.  It *might* be lazy, or not, depending on whether the JVM decides the Holder class is being "referenced" in a way that requires initialization.  And note, of course, that if lazy initialization is not desired then a plain old inited `static` is far superior to a complex initialization scheme.

Comment: BTW Holder class should be private, because in this case you can create Holder object like: Singleton.Holder = new Singleton.Holder() and initialize INSTANCE straightaway.

Comment: @HotLicks Are you talking about HotSpot JVM? Could you give me some example of this JVM behaviour because I've thought this was impossible for traditional Holder idiom.

Comment: @JakubHr thanks for your remark. just edited this

Comment: The init method must be run *before* the "first <something> reference" of the class.  (Can't recall what <something> is.)  There's no real restriction on how early it can be, and <something> is somewhat vaguely defined (even if I could remember the word).